# SQLite C++ inserting unsigned character array

Tags: c++, sqlite, unsigned

after reading a few other posts it seems like what I want may be possible, but at the moment I have an array of unsigned characters I wish to enter into a row of my table in sqlite. now I know sqlite uses UTF-8 encoding so I should I think be able to do this but I'm unsure.

at the moment my code doesn't work I have a table...

```
void PersonalDataBase::openUserDataBase()
{
    int rc;
    //table setup
    string table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERS (" \
        "_id                 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   NOT NULL," \
        "USERNAME            TEXT                  NOT NULL," \
        "PASSWORD            TEXT," \
        "USERHASH            TEXT                  NOT NULL," \
        "EVAL                TEXT                  NOT NULL," \
        "NVAL                TEXT                  NOT NULL," \
        "PVAL                TEXT," \
        "QVAL                TEXT," \
        "DVAL                TEXT);";
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    sqlite3_initialize();

    /* Open database */
    //Note rc should be checked for errors
    rc = sqlite3_open_v2("database/data/UsersDB.db", &userDB, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);

    //add table 
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(userDB, table.c_str(), -1, &stmt, 0);
    sqlite3_step(stmt);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
```

after calling this my table is created but now inserting into it...

now for inserting into my table, I create a new entry and generate my unsigned char arrays e, d, n, p, q then....

```
        string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO USERS (USERNAME,PASSWORD,USERHASH,EVAL,NVAL,PVAL,QVAL,DVAL) " \
                    "VALUES ('" + username + "', '" + password + "', "; 
        //set E
        string temp1 = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < e -> getLength(); i++)
        {
            temp1 += (char) e -> getByte(i);
        }
        insertQuery += temp1 + "', '";

        //set N
        temp1 = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < n -> getLength(); i++)
        {
            temp1 += (char) n -> getByte(i);
        }
        insertQuery += temp1 + "', '";  

        //set P
        temp1 = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < p -> getLength(); i++)
        {
            temp1 += (char) p -> getByte(i);
        }
        insertQuery += temp1 + "', '";  

        //set Q
        temp1 = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < q -> getLength(); i++)
        {
            temp1 += (char) q -> getByte(i);
        }
        insertQuery += temp1 + "', '";  

        //set D
        temp1 = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < d -> getLength(); i++)
        {
            temp1 += (char) d -> getByte(i);
        }
        insertQuery += temp1 + "');";   

        //insert Key + User data into Table
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(userDB, insertQuery.c_str(), -1, &stmt1, 0);
        sqlite3_step(stmt1);
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt1);
```

I build my query, however I'm pretty sure a part of my problem is my getByte() function returns an unsigned char, this value could be anything, it's ascii equivalent could be say ' or , characters that I think are messing up my query, my question is is there a way I can directly write my unsigned chars to my database? or should I create a function that takes them converts their 8bit to 7bit then work with chars? however this still doesn't solve my issue that it could be ' and , or others characters. anyone have any ideas on what I should do here?

Comment: I'm confused Isn't what I'm doing preparing a statement? sorry I'm new to sql, I've used it for a class before but not for c++ and not with crytpographic values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid formatting problems, use parameters:

```
string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO USERS (USERNAME,PASSWORD,USERHASH,EVAL,NVAL,PVAL,QVAL,DVAL) "
                "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
err = sqlite3_prepare_v2(userDB, insertQuery.c_str(), -1, &stmt1, 0);
// check err
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt1, 1, username.c_str(), -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt1, 2, password.c_str(), -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt1, 3, e.c_str(), -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt1, 4, n.c_str(), -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt1, 5, p.c_str(), -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt1, 6, q.c_str(), -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
// or as blob:
sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt1, 7, d.byte_ptr(), d.byte_count(), SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
err = sqlite3_step(stmt1);
```

Comment: Thanks! what is the  SQLITE_TRANSIENT option do? and what is the difference between blob and text?

Comment: [Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html). [Blob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object).